# Lightbox compatible with Jquery 1.4.4 min

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Anybody know of one or where to find one?

Comment: This is a good one for 1.4.4: http://www.chillwebdesigns.co.uk/chillbox.html

Answer (score 0):

http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html

Built on jQuery for jQuery with jQuery.